# What is the advantage of flattening dependent Promises

Tags: javascript, promises

I've read that nesting Promise continuations is bad practice. For example, [here](https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/).

```
GetCustomer().then(customer => {
    ProcessCustomer(customer).then(processingResult =>
    {
        console.log(customer);
        console.log(processingResult);
    });
});
```

As the 2nd function call relies on the output of the first, un-nesting this looks like this...

```
GetCustomer().then(customer => {
        return Promise.all([customer, ProcessCustomer(customer)]);
    }).then(results => {
        console.log(results[0]);
        console.log(results[1]);
    });
```

I personally find the nested style easier to read and reason about. I also like the strongly named variables, as apposed to accessing `results[i]`, which could be error prone.

What are the disadvantages of the first approach, and/or the advantages of the second?

Comment: Your second code block makes no sense to me at all.  Why use `Promise.all()` in that situation?  There's only one async operation - no need for `Promise.all()`.

Comment: With multiple nesting will be more difficult to find, on which level `customer` was created. Where "chaining" approach will need to look only one step back.

Comment: @jfriend00 Indeed! This was the pattern suggested in the link I posted in my question for converting from dependent nested promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 `customer` is used alongside `processingResult`. You don't hold onto it if you just `GetCustomer().then(ProcessCustomer).then(processingResult => ... )`

Comment: the async /await is like a sugar syntax for a flattened promise notation, there is a kind of convergence in the approach.

Comment: The first approach might look fine when you only have two levels, but if you have a lot of nested promises you will end up with a [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)). Promises were designed to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is these options: [How to chain and share prior results with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option to have access to both `customer` and `processingResult` without nesting would probably be to use `async/await` (ES7 feature) like this (this would need to be inside an `async` function declaration):

```
async function someFunction() {
    const customer = await GetCustomer();
    const processingResult = await ProcessCustomer(customer);
    console.log(customer);
    console.log(processingResult);
    return someValue;
}

// usage
someFunction().then(result => {
    // done here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

> What are the disadvantages of the first approach,

At just two levels like this, there are no particular disadvantages to nesting.  You MUST return the inner promise in order to be able to get final result and full error handling.  So, to use the first option properly with nesting, you would need to at least return the inner promise so you can catch all errors at the top level:

```
GetCustomer().then(customer => {
    return ProcessCustomer(customer).then(processingResult => {
        console.log(customer);
        console.log(processingResult);
        return someValue;
    });
}).catch(err => {
    // catch all errors here
    console.log(err);
});
```

If you get more levels, the nesting gets less and less readable.

> and/or the advantages of the second?

It's really just personal opinion at this point.  I'm personally not a fan of passing a raw value to `Promise.all()` just so it will pass it through to a common `.then()` handler.  It appears to make the code more complicated looking than it actually is (but that's just my opinion).  It would work just fine.

This is a place where object destructing would make things a little more readable and you need a `.catch()` handler:

```
GetCustomer().then(customer => {
    return Promise.all([customer, ProcessCustomer(customer)]);
}).then(([customer, processedCustomer]) => {
    console.log(customer);
    console.log(processedCustomer);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

For a number of other options, see here:

[How to Chain and Share Prior Results With Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714298/how-to-chain-and-share-prior-results-with-promises/28714863#28714863)